# Number validation in python?

Tags: python, random, input

> Question was to help validate text with an automated number selector in Python
>
> answer correctly below

```
from random import randrange
while True:
        try:
            userinput=int(input("Enter a number: "))
            break
        except:
            print("Only numbers you loser")
print(randrange(int(input())))
```

***just I have to press enter in the terminal before it registers that I have typed anything in***

Enter a number: a

Only numbers you loser

Enter a number: 30

30

4

Comment: You need to explicitly test for numbers that are less than 0.

Comment: by setting n=-1 when input is not a number you do randrange(0) which throws an error

Comment: Note: `isdigit()` will reject all sorts of perfectly valid `int` inputs (negative values, values with leading/trailing whitespace, etc.). Don't pre-check, just do `try: n = int(s)`, `except ValueError: ... respond to invalid value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to ask the input in an infinite loop, and break only once the value is valid (i.e. it does not throw a `ValueError` anymore).

```
from random import randrange

while True:
    try:
        n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Your input was not a number, try again.")

print(randrange(n + 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randrange
s = input('Enter a Number: ')
try: 
  n = int(s)
  print(randrange(n + 1))
except ValueError:  
  print('Enter a number instead of a letter')
```